# MySQL Procedure to Update a Row

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I can't get the following to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE base_insert
(IN in_visitor_id VARCHAR (256), IN in_booking_ref VARCHAR (256), IN in_stage_name VARCHAR (256), IN in_difficulty VARCHAR (256), IN in_lead_quality VARCHAR (256))
BEGIN
    UPDATE visitors 
    SET 
        booking_ref = in_booking_ref,
        deal_stage = in_deal_stage,
        deal_difficulty = in_deal_difficulty,
        lead_quality = in_lead_quality
    WHERE visitor_id = in_visitor_id//
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: The where statement should be terminated with ;

Comment: Looks good, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove // from WHERE

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE base_insert
(IN in_visitor_id VARCHAR (256), IN in_booking_ref VARCHAR (256), IN in_stage_name VARCHAR (256), IN in_difficulty VARCHAR (256), IN in_lead_quality VARCHAR (256))
BEGIN
    UPDATE visitors 
    SET 
        booking_ref = in_booking_ref,
        deal_stage = in_deal_stage,
        deal_difficulty = in_deal_difficulty,
        lead_quality = in_lead_quality
    WHERE visitor_id = in_visitor_id;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```